# How to ignore state with cubit in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

I'm using cubit to manage state of widgets, and I want to make widget updated only when specific type of state is emitted.

```dart
part of 'TestData.dart';

@immutable
abstract class TestState {}

class TestInitial extends TestState {}

class TestValueUpdated extends TestState {
  TestValueUpdated(this.message);
  
  final String message;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return other is TestValueUpdated && other.message == message;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => message.hashCode;
}

class TestScaleUpdated extends TestState {
  TestScaleUpdated(this.message);

  final String message;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return other is TestScaleUpdated && other.message == message;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => message.hashCode;
}
```

I created state class called `TestState`, and this class currently having 3 states : initial, value updated, scale updated

```dart
class TestData extends Cubit<TestState> {

//Codes here

  Future<void> keepPlayStatus() async {
    emit(TestValueUpdated(getTimeStamp()+" / "+getMaxTime()+"  |  "+getPosition()));
  }

  Future<void> updateScaleValueMessage() async {
    emit(TestScaleUpdated((size * 100).round().toInt().toString() + " %"));
  }
}
```

and this class called `TestData` uses `TestState` and extends `Cubit`.

Basically, when user updates zoom value by pinching the screen, this class will emit `TestScaleUpdated` state, and when user plays something, it will emit `TestValueUpdated` state.

and in UI,

```dart
//somewhere of the codes, called widget A
child: BlocBuilder<TestData, TestState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if(state is TestValueUpdated) {
      return Text(
        state.message,
        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        style: TextStyle(color: ThemeManager.getRGBfromHex(0x514745)),
      );
    } else {
      return Text(
        "00:00.000 / 00:04.800 | 1.1.1",
        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        style: TextStyle(color: ThemeManager.getRGBfromHex(0x514745)),
      );
    }
  },
)

//the other part of the codes, called widget B
child: BlocBuilder<TestData, TestState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if(state is TestScaleUpdated) {
      return Text(
        state.message,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(color: ThemeManager.getRGBfromHex(0x514745)) ,
      );
    } else {
      return Text(
        "100 %",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(color: ThemeManager.getRGBfromHex(0x514745)) ,
      );
    }
  },
)
```

I tried this code. These 2 widgets update their status when `TestData` emits some state. Problem for this code is that, if user plays something, since `TestScaleUpdated` state won't be emitted, widget B's status goes back to initial state, showing "100 %" always.

If user updates scale, then `TestValueUpdated` won't be emitted, so widget A will always have initial state, showing "00:00.000 / 00:04.800 | 1.1.1".

So what I want to perform now is that, I want to make widget ignore status update. For example, in builder of `BlocBuilder`

```dart
(context, state) {
  if(state is TestScaleUpdated) {
    return Text("Scale!");
  else if(state is TestInitial) {
    return Text("Initial!");
  } else {
    //ignore, or keep widget's status
  }
}
```

Problem here, if I explain more detailed, is this :
Let's assume that user played something, so widget A's text is changed to `00:10.000 / 00:40.000 | 2.0.0`.

Then when user tries to change scale value, not only widget B affected, but also widget A gets affected. But since `TestData` emitted only `TestScaleUpdated` state, widget A's text gets back to `00:00.000 | 00:04.800 | 1.1.1` while it should keep its text, and status.

I want to make only widget B updated when `TestScaleUpdated` is emitted, and make only widget A updated when `TestValueUpdated` is emitted. Simply, managing 2 or more widgets differently with one cubit class.

Do I have to merge these 2 states : `TestScaleUpdated`, and `TestValueUpdated` into 1 state containing 2 `message` for each widget?

or can I keep status of widget if emitted state doesn't satisfy specific condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create one state which has all the required information. But if you just want the widgets to rebuild only in certain situations, then you can do it like this for your Widget A:

```
BlocBuilder<TestData, TestState>(
  buildWhen: (oldState, newState) => newState is TestValueUpdated;
  builder: (context, state) {
      return Text(
        state is TestValueUpdated ? state.message : "00:00.000 / 00:04.800 | 1.1.1",
        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        style: TextStyle(color: ThemeManager.getRGBfromHex(0x514745)),
      );
  },
)
```

Comment: Umm, I should explain situation more detailed. Let's assume that widget A's text was `00:10:000 / 00:40.000 | 2.0.0`. But then, when user changes scale, widget A's text gets back to `00:00.000 / 00:04.800 | 1.1.1` while it should keep its time, and numbers. I want to make only widget B updated when `TestScaleUpdated` state is emitted. I can merge 2 states into 1 state, containing all required data both for widget A and B, but I don't want to create unnecessary *data*. Is merging states, making one that containing all data the only way?

Comment: Merging states is usefull but maybe it is enough to implement my above solution, since widget A then rebuilds, for example, only when the state changes accordingly. But I would do both: Implementing the buildWhen-Function of BlocBuilder and having a state which is holding all the required data.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I saw `buildWhen` now. Yes, I wanted such thing. Thanks a lot, I will accept your answer